# iOS cannot add action to the button from different view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `ViewController 1` in which I have a button, which calls `ViewController 2` using a present view controller. I have added an action to Button which is in `ViewController 2`. But Button doesn't call that action when clicked.
my code is:

To display `ViewController 2`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ViewController2 * addShot = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil];
    [addShot.addShotButton addTarget:self action:@selector(submitShot:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (IBAction)addShotButtonTapped:(id)sender{
    [addShot setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationPopover];
    [addShot setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];

    UINavigationController * nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addShot];
    [self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Everything works fine but `submitShot action` never gets called. Suggestions?

Comment: That is not a proper way to do this, you need to use delegate to achieve this.

Comment: try by changing target "self" to "addShot"

Comment: `viewDidLoad` you have showed in question is of `VC2 or VC1` and `addShotButton` is on `VC1` or `VC2` ! and where is `submitShot` method ?

Comment: This whole code is on VC1 and addShotButton is on VC2

Comment: @Rajat How do I use delegates?

Comment: then you have to use `delegate and protocols`. If you don't have idea about this then first learn it from basic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add you protocol in your ViewController2.h like this

```
@protocol  ViewController2Delegate <NSObject>

-(void) submitShotTapped;

@end
```

before your `@interface`

and in your interface declare a property of it.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<ViewController2Delegate> delegate;
```

Always use **weak** property for your delegate.

On action of your submitShot add call this delegate method like this

```
- (IBAction) submitShot:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate submitShotTapped];
}
```

Now in your ViewController1 declare that delegate like this

```
@interface TagDetails ()<ViewController2Delegate>
```

Now while creating your object of ViewController2 assign this delegate to self of ViewController1 like this

```
ViewController2 * addShot = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil];
addShot.delegate = self;
```

Then implement that delegate method in ViewController1 like this

```
-(void) submitShotTapped {
     //Shot button tapped on ViewController2
}
```

This is how you can use delegate, also remove the targets which you have added on button.

Comment: Its working . Thanks. Can you quickly suggest, how do I Share NSDictionary and arrays between two controllers?

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong, you are creating another instance of `ViewController2` which isn't on your screen and basically doing nothing:

```
ViewController2 * addShot = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil];

[addShot.addShotButton addTarget:self action:@selector(submitShot:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

It should be:

```
[self.addShotButton addTarget:self action:@selector(submitShot:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: This code should be in your `ViewController 2` not your first one, I think it would work if you put it in ViewController 2's viewDidLoad

Comment: Yeah it would but I want it on VC1

Comment: @thewarri0r9 then try put `[addShot.addShotButton addTarget:self action:@selector(submitShot:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];` right before `[self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];`, see if it works or not

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is the wrong way. Try to following code. This should work.

**ViewControler2.h**

```
 @interface ViewControler2  
    //your other stuff I guess
    @property (strong , nonatomic) UIButton *addShotButton;
  @end
```

**ViewControler2.m**

```
 @implementation ViewController2

    @synthesize addShotButton;

    - (void)viewDidLoad{
        [super viewDidLoad];
        [self.addShotButton addTarget:self action:@selector(submitShot:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    
    }
    -(void)submitShot:(id)sender{
     //Your action
    }
    @end
```

**ViewController1.h**

```
@interface ViewController1
@end
```

**ViewController1.m**

```
@implementation ViewController1
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (IBAction)addShotButtonTapped:(id)sender{
    ViewController2 * addShot = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil];
    [addShot setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationPopover];
    [addShot setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
    UINavigationController * nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addShot];
    [self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
}
@end
```